# Predicted result saving to csv from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, text-classification, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to find combined accuracy of more than 2 predicted dataframe results, 
After Prediction of Result saved result into csv and to get the Final **Combined accuracy** all the saved result is imported and **concatinated**.

But while computation it was not working as expected and came to following outcome the **results are changed on saving to csv**. Do we have another **way to save result into csv** so, **original form of result** is preserved.

```
test_result is test data having 
test_result['text'] and test_result['labels]

train_result is train data having 
train_result['text'] and t_result['sentiment]

time classifier = grid_svm.fit(train_result['text'], train_result['sentiment']) 
predicted= classifier.predict(test_result['lemma_text'])
print(classification_report(test_result['labels'], predicted))
```

the predicted classification report is as below

[image]

```
# below code is used to save result to csv 
test_result.to_csv('result/2_entertainment.csv')
# below code is used to import same result from csv  again
test_data_2 = pd.read_csv('result/2_entertainment.csv')
#But now strangely the classification report changes drastically.
# I'm not sure where the error is happening 
#it seems that while saving result the result has been swaped 
print(classification_report(test_data_2['sentiment'], test_data_2['labels']))
```

[image]